# How to turn off access logging for json requests, using nginx/uwsgi

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I have an nginx.conf file that has

```
location / {
     # see http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html
     uwsgi_pass uwsgi_devcluster;
     include uwsgi_params;
}
```

and I want to make sure that json requests to this uwsgi server are not logged, as loads are made per minute. So I tried

```
location / {
     location ~ \.json$ {
        access_log off;
     }
     # see http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html
     uwsgi_pass uwsgi_devcluster;
     include uwsgi_params;
}
```

but that gives 404 errors for those pages. How should I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location` blocks do not work like that. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

You could define two locations block, both with the necessary `uwsgi_pass` directives. The simplest solution would be:

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass uwsgi_devcluster;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
location ~ \.json$ {
    access_log off;
    uwsgi_pass uwsgi_devcluster;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `map` directive to set a variable to set the `if=condition` of the `access_log` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) for details.

Comment: Thanks. I have other location blocks above which I still want to keep in effect. So could I nest the .json match within the `location /` block, but simply repeat the uwsgi_pass etc directives? Like `location / { location ~\.json$ {access_log off;
    uwsgi_pass uwsgi_devcluster;
    include uwsgi_params;}
    uwsgi_pass uwsgi_devcluster;
    include uwsgi_params;
}`

Comment: That should work. You probably only need access_log and uwsgi_pass in the nested location block. I believe that the uwsgi_params will be inherited from the surrounding block.

Comment: And indeed you are right. Just the `access_log` and `uwsgi_pass` settings are needed inside the block.